# О запятой и тире

Tags: пунктуация

Немного не понимаю, является ли обязательной постановка двух знаков препинания в предложении - запятой и тире?
Насколько я знаю, правило используется достаточно редко. Чаще всего скопления знаков избегают.
Пример Розенталя:

> Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали.
> История техники, которая облегчает жизнь и труд людей, — вот история культуры.

Что будет, если убрать "тире"? Допустимо ли опускать такой знак?

Answer (score 1):

Ну запятая-то в обоих предложениях на месте - она закрывает придаточное предложение.

Во втором тире делает свою работу - стоит между предложениями (или - между подлежащим и сказуемым, - это уже тонкости).

(Как единый знак зап/тире употребляется при т. н. переломе конструкции; я этот знак обожаю и - поди докажи, что "конструкция" не сломана.)

В первом предложении тире факультативно, но:

красиво ж, нет?

Красивость знаков - один из краеугольных камней пунктуации, а ещё краеугольнее - полиграфии.

Правила не нарушены? Нет. Вот и радуем глаз и ухо.

Comment: Надо, наоборот, доказывать, что она сломана.

Comment: В первом предложении тире по причине контраста в сложносочинённом.

Comment: Нетути контраста. Я отвечал, мы оба замолчали, - и где он? Отвечание и молчание?

Comment: Контраст это неожиданная или резкая, или эмоциональная смена обстановки. Тут так же, как когда кто-то задаст неудобный вопрос за ужином и все замолчат. В справочнике Розенталя есть пример на эту тему: ‟Тут раздался лёгкий свист — и Дубровский умолк (П.)”.